# PHP: Run function in background (and track it?)

Tags: php, ajax, multithreading, background

I have several parts to this problem.  First, I've got a website and I'm trying to import data from another system, but the import could take several minutes.  Meanwhile I'd like to let the user go on and continue working on the website, running the import in the background.

I'm doing my dev on a local WAMP server, but the test and production environments are Linux.

I've found several answers on here, some which suggest using `pcntl_fork()`, others suggesting running a command-line PHP script and others suggesting Ajax.

My problems with each of these approaches:

- The `pcntl_fork()` spins up another instance of apache, which isn't what I want.
- Ajax seems to lock the website until the import completes.
- I'm trying to run a single FUNCTION rather than an entire script, so I don't believe the command-line will work.

Anyone have any ideas how to run this exclusively in the background?  Also, any way to check and see if the process is complete?

Comment: [This](http://bytes.com/topic/php/answers/825299-possible-run-php-function-background#post3292811) might be of some help, and maybe even a check of the [`exec()` Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php) ?

Comment: What kind of data are you importing? Is it data you query intensive on in the rest of your website? Because you say that an ajax request locks your website. For me that sounds probably like a database table lock, because you are trying to query on tables that are both used for inserting and reading at the same time

Comment: @cocheese is right. Ajax (unless set to async) should not lock your website unless you are modifying tables that the rest of the site uses. If that's the case you are better off storing your jobs in a queue or a separate table for batch processing overnight/when your site receives less traffic